# PHP PDO double inserting

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert, double

Okay, I have a very weird problem and I don't know what can be causing it. I have been working with PHP for 3 years but I have no idea what is going on now.
I used a very simple code using PDO to insert into db:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db', "root", "");
$del = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_rate VALUES(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)");
$del->execute();
```

Nothing more, there is only  and  tags but no thing more and what it does is that whenever I refresh the website it double inserts into database.
I was looking at these 3 lines for 2 hours and I don't know why it always inserts twice.

If anyone ever had that problem please tell me how to solve it or what can be causing it :x
Thank you!

Comment: What you posted, won't cause that. You say when you refresh the website. Does this involve a form? Set inside a function and being called/included twice?

Comment: No, I am not including anything, my index.php has only this:
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 *my code above*
</body>
</html>

Comment: Is there a trigger on the table?

Comment: I am not sure what trigger is but I didn't add anything to the table. Is there any way to check it?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with duplicate inserts because retrieving the query and then executing doubled inserted:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db', "root", "");
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_rate VALUES(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)";
$del->query($sql)->execute();
```

This was fixed by removing the execute() call:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db', "root", "");
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_rate VALUES(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)";
$del->query($sql);
```

Gives the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I don't know how but it's solved. I just tried to delete the file with database connect and then I pasted it on ftp again and now it's working (1 insert after refresh) so I still have no idea why D:
Thank you all who helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

If you execute your script just from refresh browser page or visit page first time browser will also load favicon.ico and can loads index.php second time. It is couse of double insert (all php operation are dobules). It is based on your webserver settings.

Try to use POST method check in your php script before executes code. This trick work because browser loads favicon uses GET method.